# c# "Unable to copy... because being used by another process" when building

Tags: c#

This is NOT the same exact issue as other SIMILAR questions.

I am running 50 or so instances of my code. These instances run through the day.

Sometimes I wish to start another instance with slightly MODIFY code whilst leaving the others running.

I get the "Unable to copy" error when building when I try to do this. Is there a way around it?

Comment: You cannot change (during build) binaries that are being executed. You have would have to start 50 or so instances from copied location.

Comment: Why? Do the running instances reference the binaries (on disk) whilst running?

Comment: You cannot modify a file while it's being used, it's how Windows works!! It's not about references, it's about a file being used by someone else. Imagine you are reading a document that gets entirely modified while you are reading it, how would the program react against that change? Read how Windows work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple way around: **Don't** run your 50 instances from your build output directory. Copy your binaries from your build output to another directory and start your instances from there.

If you do so, you won't have problems deploying a new modified version. Of course you cannot exchange the running binaries with that new version, but you may copy your new version to another directory and start it from there.

UPDATE: Another way around would be to temporarily change the output directory of your deploy process. But I'd prefer to move *productive* binaries away from the build output location.

Comment: OK. I guess copy will be best approach. I didn't realise that binaries were referenced.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are running your code and trying to copy it at the same time.  If you think you will need to copy/change your code while it is running later, you should make a copy before you run it.  That way, if you need a copy to modify, you can copy the copy that's not running.

Comment: yes exactly. I understand that this is the issue. I am just asking if there is a way of avoiding the unnecessary(for me) step of creating a copy?

Comment: @ManInMoon No. You can not overwrite executing binaries.

Comment: @ManInMoon Though you could temporarily change your deploy directory.

Comment: Why is that? Are the binaries on disk referenced during run-time?